# Realm.getInstance(context) throws Annotation processor may not have been executed

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, annotations, realm

When trying to get Realm instance i got the following exception -

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated io.realm.HallOfFameHolderRealmProxy class: Annotation processor may not have been executed.
```

My class code is -

```
@RealmClass
```

public class HallOfFameHolder extends RealmObject {

```
private static final String TAG = "HallOfFameHolder";

private int mId;
private String mTrackName;
private Date mDateTime;
private String mTimeStr;
private String mDateStr;
private long mTotalRunTime;
private String mTotalRunTimeStr;
private int mNumOfLaps;
private long mBestLapTime;
private String mBestLapTimeStr;
private boolean mDryTrack;
private float mGearRatio;
private int mSrJetting;

@Ignore
private int mSessionId;

public void setData(String trackName, Date dateTime, String timeStr,
        String dateStr, long totalRunTime, String totalRunTimeStr,
        int numOfLaps, long bestLapTime, String bestLapTimeStr,
        boolean dryTrack, float gearRatio, int srJetting) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setData");
    mTrackName = trackName;
    mDateTime = dateTime;
    mTimeStr = timeStr;
    mDateStr = dateStr;
    mTotalRunTime = totalRunTime;
    mTotalRunTimeStr = totalRunTimeStr;
    mNumOfLaps = numOfLaps;
    mBestLapTime = bestLapTime;
    mBestLapTimeStr = bestLapTimeStr;
    mDryTrack = dryTrack;
    mGearRatio = gearRatio;
    mSrJetting = srJetting;
}

public void setData(int id, String trackName, Date dateTime,
        String timeStr, String dateStr, long totalRunTime,
        String totalRunTimeStr, int numOfLaps, long bestLapTime,
        String bestLapTimeStr, boolean dryTrack, float gearRatio,
        int srJetting) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setData");
    mTrackName = trackName;
    mDateTime = dateTime;
    mTimeStr = timeStr;
    mDateStr = dateStr;
    mTotalRunTime = totalRunTime;
    mTotalRunTimeStr = totalRunTimeStr;
    mNumOfLaps = numOfLaps;
    mBestLapTime = bestLapTime;
    mBestLapTimeStr = bestLapTimeStr;
    mDryTrack = dryTrack;
    mGearRatio = gearRatio;
    mSrJetting = srJetting;
    mId = id;
}   

public int getmId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setmId(int mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

public String getmTrackName() {
    return mTrackName;
}

public void setmTrackName(String mTrackName) {
    this.mTrackName = mTrackName;
}

public Date getmDateTime() {
    return mDateTime;
}

public void setmDateTime(Date mDateTime) {
    this.mDateTime = mDateTime;
}

public String getmTimeStr() {
    return mTimeStr;
}

public void setmTimeStr(String mTimeStr) {
    this.mTimeStr = mTimeStr;
}

public String getmDateStr() {
    return mDateStr;
}

public void setmDateStr(String mDateStr) {
    this.mDateStr = mDateStr;
}

public long getmTotalRunTime() {
    return mTotalRunTime;
}

public void setmTotalRunTime(long mTotalRunTime) {
    this.mTotalRunTime = mTotalRunTime;
}

public String getmTotalRunTimeStr() {
    return mTotalRunTimeStr;
}

public void setmTotalRunTimeStr(String mTotalRunTimeStr) {
    this.mTotalRunTimeStr = mTotalRunTimeStr;
}

public int getmNumOfLaps() {
    return mNumOfLaps;
}

public void setmNumOfLaps(int mNumOfLaps) {
    this.mNumOfLaps = mNumOfLaps;
}

public long getmBestLapTime() {
    return mBestLapTime;
}

public void setmBestLapTime(long mBestLapTime) {
    this.mBestLapTime = mBestLapTime;
}

public String getmBestLapTimeStr() {
    return mBestLapTimeStr;
}

public void setmBestLapTimeStr(String mBestLapTimeStr) {
    this.mBestLapTimeStr = mBestLapTimeStr;
}

public boolean ismDryTrack() {
    return mDryTrack;
}

public void setmDryTrack(boolean mDryTrack) {
    this.mDryTrack = mDryTrack;
}

public float getmGearRatio() {
    return mGearRatio;
}

public void setmGearRatio(float mGearRatio) {
    this.mGearRatio = mGearRatio;
}

public int getmSrJetting() {
    return mSrJetting;
}

public void setmSrJetting(int mSrJetting) {
    this.mSrJetting = mSrJetting;
}


// DO NOT Delete the next 2 methods
public int getmSessionId() {
    return mSessionId;
}

public void setmSessionId(int sessionId) {
    mSessionId = sessionId;
}
```

}

I'm using Eclipse and realm-0.78.0.jar.
How it can be resolved?

Comment: What version of the JVM are you using? Does adding the @RealmClass annotation to your model class help?

Comment: Im using:
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
And using -
@RealmClass
public class HallOfFameHolder extends RealmObject {

Comment: Your setData methods should make the annotation processor fail. Do you have any logs of the build process?

Comment: What annotation should setData(...) method should has?

Comment: the setter should not have any data, but the annotation processor should fail if there is any setter not associated to a field.

Comment: Can you add an example of a class extends RealmObject with setters methods?

Comment: Sending you the code which save the data to DB          Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
  realm.beginTransaction();
  HallOfFameHolder holder = realm.createObject(HallOfFameHolder.class);
  holder.setData(trackName, dateTime, timeStr, dateStr, totalRunTime, totalRunTimeStr, numOfLaps, bestLapTime, bestLapTimeStr, dryTrack, gearRatio, srJetting);
  realm.commitTransaction();  
The failure occurs in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with Proguard http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/

```
ProGuard
Realm generates a proxy class for each RealmObject at compile time. To ensure that these classes can be found after running an obufuscation and static analysis tool like ProGuard add the configuration below to your ProGuard configuration file.

-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
-keep class io.realm.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

Does making these changes fix the issue?

Comment: Hmm... I had a lot of problems originally when I tried to implement Realm into my project.. What really helped me was to make the most simple subclass of RealmObject possible and then slowly add stuff so it fits my specifications. That helped me a lot to figure out the quirks of Realm. The documentation is still missing a lot (which is expected since its still in beta). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a custom method (setData) in your model class, which is not currently supported in Realm. We're working on ways to allow this while disallowing developers to shoot themselves in the foot.